# Looking for a paper by Landau and one by Watson

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For the purposes of a project, I've been looking for the following two papers referred to in Serre's "Divisibilité de certaines fonctions arithmétiques":

Landau (E.), - Über die Eitenlung  der positiven ganzen Zahlen in vier Klassen nach der Mindestzahl der zu ihrer additiven Zusammensetzung erforderlichen Quadrate, Arch. der Math. und Phys.(3) 13, 1908, p. 305-312

Watson: (G.N.), - Über Ramanujansche Kongruenzeigenschaften der Zerfällungsanzahlen (I),  Math. Z., t. 39, 1935, p. 712-731.

Despite my best attempts, I have been unable to find the papers themselves or the relevant issues of these journals either. I would be really grateful if someone to provide me a link to either or tell me how I might find them.

(Perhaps I'm asking for too much, but are there English translations of these available somewhere?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the Landau paper at the Internet Archive: https://archive.org/details/archivdermathem37unkngoog/page/n324/mode/1up

Here's the Watson paper at the EuDML: https://eudml.org/doc/168581, which links to the GDZ for a scan.

Comment: To answer your more general question of finding old stuff, EuDML has very good coverage of old European journals, especially German ones, and the Internet Archive is worth always a search for 19th century or early 20th century stuff.